# Security in WebAPI App with MVC Client OpenID / OAuth

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid, authorization, asp.net-web-api

I know there is a lot of questions out there already and I've been reading blogs and looking at samples for well over a week and I'm still a little hazy on how some of this is going to work in the real world.  The samples are very helpful, some are very complex some are simple, none have really clarified some of my questions.

The system comprises:

- Web App (own IIS site, with SSL, consumes Public API)
- Public API (own IIS site, with SSL)
- Desktop Widget
- Mobile (iOS, Android)
- 3rd Party apps

How best to handle user registration and account creation?  Whilst offering OpenID there also needs to be a 'local' login to the web application.  Having a method on the API that accepts base data types (strings/dates etc...) values and then creates an account is asking for trouble and a red flag to the spammers.  Would it be best to handle this exclusively through the web site employing visual CAPTCHA checks?  How does the Facebook mobile app handle this registration scenario?

Lots of samples also seem to use small subsets of the default Forms Authentication database for Membership. They then use Entity Framework and the Membership, WebSecurity or FormsAuthentication, Roles Provider classes in various different ways depending on use case.  Are there any alternatives to this approach to consider for the security backend?  Our DB guy is considering rolling our own but then we also need to build our own user management app :(

Once a user is registered and logged in to the web app I can't see any way around continuing to authenticate and authorize each call on the WebAPI.  I'm assuming at the moment that the API should just implement OAuth and treat the web app as another client app like the mobile app and 3rd party apps.

I think I've read too much without playing with code to settle this in my head.  There are so many approaches.

TIA,

Comment: Every call to protected Web API controller action methods needs to be authorized, typically this is performed by an action filter prior to the execution of the method. The authentication HTTP header would contain the authentication information using the scheme you have chosen to protect your resources. One approach is to use the OAuth WRAP scheme and send a bearer token in the Authentication header which the filter would verify and examine to determine if access/execution will be granted.

Comment: I've not come across OAuth WRAP, I'll go and have a read.  One question I have is if this login happens at the web site, how would I then proceed to call the API?

In the ASP.NET MVC4 template Forms Auth template what would I do in place of this:

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, createPersistentCookie: false);

To start calling the API as an authenticated user?

Comment: http://wiki.oauth.net/w/page/12238537/OAuth%20WRAP

"OAuth WRAP has been deprecated in favor of the OAuth 2.0 specification which the IETF community has been working on over the past six months."

Comment: The OAuth WRAP scheme is still valid, they use it for authorization in platforms like Azure. Conceptually, you serialize a signed set of assertions and send them in the Authorization header with the scheme of the header indicating the authentication type. The action filter then inspects/deserializes the assertion, verifies its digital signature and then makes authorization decisions based on the set of claims presented in the assertion. Assertion is usually a JWT, SWT, or SAML token. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-7 of the OAuth2 specification.

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.8 for info on Authorization header

Comment: Thanks Oppositional, will go ingest this.  Many thanks for the links.